# Get Search Url Parameters from Google to Person Site?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to get the URL address like this?

https://www.google.com/search?q=cheaperst+car+mudah&oq=cheaperst+car+mudah&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.4807j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
to my Website

Google to MySite.com

Using Javascript

Comment: `Is it possible to get the URL address like this?` what does this mean?

Comment: For my E-commerce website, i am using google ad words that linked to particular links to provide different brand products?
i need to pass users URL to My Website so i can process according to their need?
example they search for local cars, from local cars i can populate some brands that might suite to my customer

Comment: so pass google search ? [q=] to my website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes -

```
document.referrer;
```

This will return the whole URL. It won't pass anything after a `#` in the URL but will get you the whole query string etc.

You can get the parameters in various ways from a URL using JavaScript. This is one example:

```js
var referrer = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=cheaperst+car+mudah';

//var referrer = document.referrer; <-- uncomment this to use the referrer

var url = new URL(referrer);
var q = url.searchParams.get('q');
console.log(q);
```